# c++ operations with file streams: when to check for error?

Tags: c++, iostream

Let's say I need to perform several read or write operations on a stream and throw an exception if any of them ended with an error. Is there any difference between the following two ways:

```
{
  std::ifstream ifs("filename");
  int i;
  std::string s;
  long l;
  //all variables are local, so I'm not interested in them in case of exception

  //first way
  if(!ifs >> i) throw runtime_error("Bad file");
  if(!std::getline(ifs, s)) throw runtime_error("Bad file");
  if(!ifs >> l) throw runtime_error("Bad file");

  //second way
  ifs >> i;
  std::getline(ifs, s);
  ifs >> l;
  if(!ifs) throw runtime_error("Bad file");

  //do something with variables
}
```

If there is no difference, then are there any pitfalls in similar cases which I should know?

Comment: I am new to C++, but in the second way shoudn't `if (! ifs)` be checked first before any operation on the stream object? In C i always do `if (!fp) 
 fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file");`

Comment: @NVSAbhilash You are correct. You could also check `if (!ifs.is_open())` if you want to be more explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable exceptions:

```
ifs.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
```

In this case an exception of `std::ios_base::failure` type will be thrown if stream fails to read something properly.

Comment: Thanks, it suits my particular case. Still, it's interesting whether my second way is safe or not.

Comment: Well, it has basically the same effect as first, however delayed error detection tend to complicate things.

Comment: @DmitryJ for your second you could `if(!(ifs >> i) || !std::getline(ifs, s) || !(ifs >> l)) throw runtime_error("Bad file");` Kicks out early on first fail, so this has the behaviour of 1 with the reduced repetition of 2.